# PHP string concatenation error. Can anyone correct it?

Tags: php, string-concatenation

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
        $c =  '<div class="desc">';
    if( $_POST['login_post'] == '1') { 
    $username = $_POST['user_login'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
        $message = log_in_user($username, $password);
    }
    display_message($message); 
    $c .= '<form name="loginform" id="loginform" method="post" action="">
                            <label>Username:</label>
                            <div><input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_username"  value="" size="20"  maxlength="40" tabindex="10" /></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="group">
                            <label>Password:</label>
                            <div><input type="password" name="password" id="user_password"  value="" size="20"  maxlength="40" tabindex="20" /></div>
                            </div>
                             <input type="hidden" name="login_post" value="1"/>

                            <div class="group">
                            <label></label>
                            <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="bluebutton" value="Log In Now" /><span class="forgotlink"><a href="/forgot-password/">Forgot your password?</a></span></div>
                            </div> 
                </form>

                    </div>';
    $c = str_replace('%value%',5,$c);
    return $c;
```

That `display_message($message);` function is supposed to display the message inside the `desc` div. Instead, it is displaying above (outside) the `desc` div.

Am I concatenating PHP code incorrectly? If yes, can some one correct me? Thanks!

### Update:

Here is my display_message function:

```
function display_message( $message = false ) {
    if( is_wp_error( $message ) ) {
        echo '<div class="errorMessage"><p>' . $message->get_error_message() . '</p></div>';    
    }
    elseif ($message != '') {
        echo '<div class="successMessage"><p>' . $message . '</p></div>';   
    }
}
```

Comment: Does display_message() return a value, or does it simply have an echo within the function itself?

Comment: @MarkBaker I updated my display_message function code in the question. Please check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display_message()` will print out the message instead of concatenating it. Try changing `display_message($message);` to `$c .= htmlspecialchars($message);` and it should end up inside the div as it is supposed to.

Edit: Since display_message does more than just display the message, it needs to be rewritten slightly;

```
function format_message( $message = false ) {
    if( is_wp_error( $message ) ) {
        return '<div class="errorMessage"><p>' . $message->get_error_message() . '</p></div>';    
    }
    elseif ($message != '') {
        return '<div class="successMessage"><p>' . $message . '</p></div>';   
    }
}
```

and the concatenation should instead be;

```
$c .= format_message($message);
```

Comment: That is not going to work if `display_message()` prints or echoes something.

Comment: @jeroen Yes my display_message echoes messages. I updated the question with my display_message function

Comment: @user1091558 Updated my answer with the new info.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks for your answer. That display message function also used by some other pages. But string concatenation requires only for my login page. If i change display_message function won't it affect other pages which uses that function?

Comment: @user1091558 That's why I made it into a new `format_message()` function so it wouldn't affect other pages. You could make display_message into just an `echo format_message($message)` if you decide to go this way and want to eliminate some code.

Comment: One more problem. When i use your code it displays as html. I mean like this. `<div class="errorMessage"><p>You forgot to enter your Password.</p></div>` How to fix this?

Comment: @user1091558 Ah, yes, the htmlspecialchars will make that happen. Removed it from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your function `display_message()` echoes something, you need to use output buffering to capture the result and add it to your `$c` variable. Otherwise it gets echoed right away.

**Edit:** With output buffering:

```
ob_start();
display_message($message); 
$c .= ob_get_contents();            // adding output to the variable
ob_end_clean();
```

A better option would probably be to have `display_message()` return a string and add that string to `$c`.

Based on your edit, I would just change the function to:

```
function display_message( $message = false ) {
    if( is_wp_error( $message ) ) {
        return '<div class="errorMessage"><p>' . $message->get_error_message() . '</p></div>';    
    }
    elseif ($message != '') {
        return '<div class="successMessage"><p>' . $message . '</p></div>';   
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

and do:

```
$c .= display_message($message);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer jeroen. But that display message function also used by some other pages. But string concatenation requires only for my login page. If i change display_message function won't it affect other pages which uses that function?

Comment: @user1091558 Yes it would. In that case you would have to use output buffering to capture the result and avoid it gets echoed right away. I'll add a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

try loading the login result into another variable, then displaying it, after that concenating it to $message.

```
$c =  '<div class="desc">';
if( $_POST['login_post'] == '1') { 
$username = $_POST['user_login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
    $login_message = log_in_user($username, $password);
}
display_message($login_message); 
$c .= $login_message . '<form name="loginform" id="loginform" method="post" action="">
                        <label>Username:</label>
                        <div><input type="text" name="user_login" id="user_username"  value="" size="20"  maxlength="40" tabindex="10" /></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="group">
                        <label>Password:</label>
                        <div><input type="password" name="password" id="user_password"  value="" size="20"  maxlength="40" tabindex="20" /></div>
                        </div>
                         <input type="hidden" name="login_post" value="1"/>

                        <div class="group">
                        <label></label>
                        <div><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="bluebutton" value="Log In Now" /><span class="forgotlink"><a href="/forgot-password/">Forgot your password?</a></span></div>
                        </div> 
            </form>

                </div>';
$c = str_replace('%value%',5,$c);
return $c;
```